# Typescript - Possible to have generic type as parameter without the generic element to it?

Tags: generics, typescript, proxy

I want to be able to access a generic type without the generics.... is that possible?

If I have a generic interface, for example

```
interface GenIntf<T1, T2> {
  someGenFunct(param: P1): T2;
}
```

And I have a factory class whose job it is to create proxies someGenFunct:

```
class ProxyFactory {
  create(genIntf: GenIntf): any {
    return new Proxy(genIntf.someGenFunct, {});
  }
}
```

So here I don't want the factory to know anything about the generic types of the GenIntf, I just want to make sure that an implementation of GenIntf is provided. But this will fail unless I changed it to

```
create<A, B>(genIntf: GenIntf<A, B>) {
```

but then this is more difficult to work with abstractly.

Comment: typescript 2.3 currently in release candidate (`npm i typescript@2.3`) will allow you to specify defaults like `interface GenInft<A = {}, B = {}> {someGenFunct(param: P1): T2;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `any` type in the type arguments:

```
class ProxyFactory {
  create(genIntf: GenIntf<any, any>): any {
    return new Proxy(genIntf.someGenFunct, {});
  }
}
```

**Sidenote:** You probably don't want an `any` return type since they should be avoided in order to prevent using a return value incorrectly. I copied and left it as-is from the code in the question.

---

Overall though, it's probably best to do what you suggested in the question:

```
class ProxyFactory {
  create<A, B>(genIntf: GenIntf<A, B>) {
    return new Proxy(genIntf.someGenFunct, {});
  }
}

const genIntf = ...;
const proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
const proxy = proxyFactory.create(genIntf);
```

**Default Type Argument**

In [TS 2.3+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/27/announcing-typescript-2-3/), you might consider using a default type argument:

```
interface GenIntf<T1 = any, T2 = any> {
  someGenFunct(param: T1): T2;
}
```

But that affects the interface itself, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I kept trying to put ? instead and compiler complained

Comment: I can sort of  understand the `any` as a type argument but they should be `{}` and the return type annotation is flat out wrong. -1

Comment: @AluanHaddad why is the return type wrong? It's copied from the question. Maybe the asker really wants to return type to be `any`... it was explicitly typed afterall. Also, why should it be `{}` instead of `any`? The asker is asking for it to be compatible with any type specified in the generic types and `any` fulfills that requirement.

Comment: `{}` is what the compiler uses by default when it cannot infer a generic type argument. You're right that return type is in the question. I missed that. I will remove downvote for that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad if `{}` is used then the return value of `genIntf.someGenFunct` will be `{}`. So the following: `const str: string = genIntf.someGenFunct({});` would be a compile error with `{}` and ok with `any`. That compile error may be desired. In my opinion, the decision to use `{}` or `any` should be made on this basis.

Comment: I was talking about the type arguments. The return type is another story and I think `Proxy` is a special and relatively uncommon case. It is better to wait until you need an `any` than to add one prematurely because you usually do not need one. In general not being eager to specify a return type is leads to improved inferences. I see insane code like `function f(): any {return [1,2,3];}` all the time, and you must admit that is awful.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah, I agree. In this specific case and in most cases it would be better to not use `any` at all. There are a few cases where `any` is useful, but it's extremely rare... I believe if used its scope should be limited to the scope of a function at most in order to prevent mistakes.